# Unix - Format XML to single line nodes

Tags: xml, shell, unix

Is there a (unix) shell script to format XML into single lines?

I need to transform the following:

```
<root>
    <foo a="1">lorem 1</foo>
    <bar value="ipsum 1" />
</root>
<root>
    <foo a="2">lorem 2</foo>
    <bar value="ipsum 2" />
</root>
```

... into something like this:

```
<root><foo a="1">lorem 1</foo><bar value="ipsum 1" /></root>
<root><foo a="2">lorem 2</foo><bar value="ipsum 2" /></root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `tr` and `sed`:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file.xml | sed 's/>[ \t]*</></g' | sed 's/<\/root><root>/<\/root>\n<root>/g'
```

So, basically, you are replacing all new lines with a regular space using `tr` because it handles multiple lines better then `sed`.  Then you are using `sed` to trim down the extra spaces and finally separate `root` elements by a new line.

**UPDATE**:  the command now removes both spaces and tabs.

Comment: awesome, Thanks very much. Works a treat

Comment: "/n" in the last sed needs to be escaped .. so its "//n"

Comment: Any way to overwrite the input file?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
   echo "this script expects one single file name"
   exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f $1 ]
then
    echo "invalid file name: $1"
    exit 2
fi
# suppress leading spaces, then remote '\n', then add '\n' only after </root>
sed 's/^\s*//g' $1 | tr -d '\n' | sed 's,</root>,</root>\n,g'
```

say you called it `script.sh`

you may execute it doing:
`./script.sh file_containing_the_xml_hunk`

it will print the result in the standard output